# Modules declared in files Swift project on Linux

Tags: swift, linux, fedora

I'm trying to start a new Swift project for some training purposes on **Fedora 30.0**. The project consists of 2 simple files:

**main.swift**

```swift
let req: Request = RequestImpl()
req.sendRequest(url: "hello")
```

**Request.swift**

```swift
protocol Request {
    func sendRequest(url: String)
}

final class RequestImpl: Request {

    // MARK: - Request

    func sendRequest(url: String) {
        print(url)
    }
}
```

**Problem**

When I run the command `swiftc main.swift` on the terminal, I get the following error:

```
$ swiftc main.swift 
main.swift:1:10: error: use of undeclared type 'Request'
let req: Request = RequestImpl()
         ^~~~~~~
```

**P.S:** I run `swiftc Request.swift` before I run the above command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should compile, but print doesn't work:

`$ swiftc Request.swift main.swift`

If you want create module with multiple files and run it, I will suggest [create executable package, build and run it](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#creating-an-executable-package).

Comment: It is compiled without errors, but it doesn't print the argument passed to `RequestImpl` class